# WebGL drawing failure after mouse click

Tags: html, opengl-es, webgl

I have a helper method `drawRect(p1, p2)` that draws a rectangle (in orthographic projection). The code works fine if I do this:

```
function webGLStart() {
    // initialization code

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixLoc, false, pMatrix);

    drawRect(new Point(10, 10), new Point(50, 50));
}
```

Now suppose I want to render a new rectangle after every mouse click. So I cleared the canvas, set up the projection matrix and moved the `drawRect` call in mouse down handler. And it is not working.

```
function webGLStart() {
    // initialization code

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixLoc, false, pMatrix);

    canvas.onmousedown = handleMouseDown;
}

function handleMouseDown(event) {
    // x, y depends on click coordinate
    drawRect(new Point(x, y), new Point(x + 20, y + 20));
}
```

The whole canvas is getting vanished after mouse click. However, if I store the information of all rectangles in an array and in mouse handler I clear the canvas and then draw all rectangles from the array then there is no problem. In other words if I re-render the complete scene then there is no problem.

So my question is: is it not possible to draw one after another without clearing the whole canvas and refreshing everything?

Comment: Does WebGL/html5 utilize multiple threads? I'm wondering if handleMouseDown runs on a UI thread or something which doesn't have the opengl context. Also maybe try calling glGetError after drawRect to see if there's something funny going on.

Comment: @Tim, but if I clear and re-render everything within mouse handler then it works fine.

Comment: Can you put up the code to drawRect, plus any other code that contains opengl commands in your drawing loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "preserve" the background then you must use the `preserveDrawingBuffer` flag:

```
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer:true} );
```

See these recent answers:

[When WebGL decide to update the display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491417/when-webgl-decide-to-update-the-display)

[Webgl update region using viewport+scissor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742941/webgl-update-region-using-viewportscissor)