# webGL draw in event handler seems to clear the canvas

Tags: javascript, webgl

Here is a very lightly reworked introductory example from [webglfundamentals.com](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVYrZd

Mousedown on the canvas to draw a new rectangle. The previously drawn rectangles are cleared. Why? The for loop and the event handler are calling the exact same function.

Relevant code:

```
// Draw 50 random rectangles in random colors.
// They draw on top of each other, as expected.
for ( var i = 0; i < 50; i += 1 ) {
  drawARandomRectangle( gl );
}

// Draw one rectangle on the canvas in response to a canvas mousedown.
// The buffer seems to be cleared, only a single new rectangle shows.
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function( e ){
  drawARandomRectangle( gl );
});
```

I have figured out that initializing the context with `preserveDrawingBuffer` causes the mousedown rectangle to be drawn on top of the existing rectangles:

```
var gl = canvas.getContext( "webgl", {
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true
} );
```

But I've also read that the performance of `preserveDrawingBuffer` is poor, and it doesn't quite explain why the in-loop calls and the mousedown call render differently.

Comment: poor is relative. It's probably no more than 10% slower, often not slower at all. On any machine that support anti-aliasing with anti-aliasing on (the default) there's no difference in speed because anti-aliasing requires a "resolve" step which is effectively a copy. It's only likely slower on some mobile phones and then it's not going to be slower if you actually need to keep the contents around.

Answer (score 4):

Use `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`

```
var gl = canvas.getContext( "webgl", { antialias: false, preserveDrawingBuffer: true} )
```

details here [WebGL drawing failure after mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843492/webgl-drawing-failure-after-mouse-click)