# Mouseclick changes the behavior of WebGL code

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

I have an array of three set of vertices which I use to draw three points on the screen. I added another vertex to my array of vertices using the push() method of javascript after initially initializing it with three vertices. I wanted to see if I could successfully add a new vertex after initializing the array and show the point on the screen, which I was able to do using the following code

```
     var vertices = [
       -0.25, 0.0, 0.0,
       -0.25,0.25,0.0,
       -0.25, 0.5, 0.0,

     ];

     var vertex_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
     var coord = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coordinates");
     gl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);
     gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
     gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 3);

     //pushing a new vertex
     vertices.push(-0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
     gl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);
     gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 3, 1);
```

this results in the following image

[image]

Then I decided to change my code to this: initially there will be three points on the screen, and after I make a mouseClick event, another point will be added to the screen. So, I created a mouseclick event and I cut paste the code of adding a new vertex to the array and drawing it to this event, like this:

```
    canvas.onmousedown = function(){
        vertices.push(-0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 3, 1);
      
        
     };
```

But, the result is, when I run the program, I initially see three points on a greyish background, as it is supposed to do. But after making a mouseclick, the greyish background and the three points disappear and I just see a point on the white background like this:

[image: after mouseclick]

Now, I don't understand why this is happening because I just copy pasted my previous code inside a mouseclick event, and if the previous code is showing me four points, why is the current code initially showing me three points and just one point after the mouseclick? Here, you will also notice that, in my previous code, when I am drawing the fourth point after drawing the three points, I am not redrawing all the previous three points, I am just drawing the fourth point. The code for that is

```
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 3, 1);
```

But, after the adding the mouseclick, if I draw all the points like this, then I am able to initially see the three points and then another point gets added after the mouseclick:

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 4);
```

Which is surprising as I did not use gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); to clear the buffer, and yet it seems like the buffer is getting cleared when onMouseDown() is called. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

We have to turn on preserveDrawingBuffer like this to preserve the buffer:

```
    var gl = canvas.getContext( "webgl", { antialias: false, preserveDrawingBuffer: true} )
```

more details can be found here [WEBGL drawing failure after mouseclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843492/webgl-drawing-failure-after-mouse-click)